# How to make a JSON String to JSON

Tags: php, json

```
"villageJson": "{\"newShopTraps\":[6,6,3,0,0,4,2,0,2],\"cooldowns\":[],\"last_league_shuffle\":1,\"decos\":[{\"data\":18000031,\"x\":2,\"y\":36},{\"data\":18000011,\"x\":4,\"y\":36},{\"data\":18000027,\"x\":6,\"y\":38},{\"data\":18000012,\"x\":6,\"y\":40},{\"data\":18000033,\"x\":6,\"y\":36}],\"edit_mode_shown\":true,\"buildings\":[{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000001,\"x\":20,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":22,\"y\":33,\"res_timer\":0},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":9,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":28,\"y\":5},{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000014,\"x\":20,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":10,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":34,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":16,\"y\":33,\"res_timer\":120625},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000003,\"x\":21,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000005,\"x\":13,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":34,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":10,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":15,\"y\":9},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":6,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":8,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":10,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":12,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":29,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000013,\"x\":13,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000007,\"x\":29,\"y\":33},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000005,\"x\":27,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000003,\"x\":27,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":27,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":30,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":30},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":31},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":31,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":34,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":35,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":33},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":34},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":19,\"y\":33,\"res_timer\":120624},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":34,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":34,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":11,\"y\":5,\"res_timer\":120160},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":25,\"y\":33,\"res_timer\":120716},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":21,\"y\":5,\"res_timer\":0},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":15,\"y\":5,\"res_timer\":0},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":10,\"y\":17,\"res_timer\":120216},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":8,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":35},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":35,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":34,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":31,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":30,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":29,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":10},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":9},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":24,\"y\":9},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":14,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000012,\"x\":13,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":24,\"y\":5,\"res_timer\":120218},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":30,\"y\":13,\"res_timer\":120687},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000011,\"x\":16,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000020,\"x\":6,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":14,\"y\":29,\"res_timer\":120626},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":6},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":5},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000013,\"x\":24,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000011,\"x\":27,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":11,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":18,\"y\":5,\"res_timer\":120217},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":28,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":34,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":35},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":34},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":33},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":31},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":30},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":5},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":6},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":9},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":10},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":12,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":29,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":10,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":30,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":25,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":17,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000013,\"x\":30,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000023,\"x\":10,\"y\":20,\"res_timer\":40689},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000012,\"x\":30,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000024,\"x\":17,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000026,\"x\":6,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000022,\"x\":17,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000028,\"x\":24,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":7,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000005,\"x\":23,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000003,\"x\":17,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":6,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":8,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":23,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000013,\"x\":18,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000012,\"x\":21,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000011,\"x\":20,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000023,\"x\":20,\"y\":9,\"res_timer\":40691},{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000026,\"x\":6,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":1,\"data\":1000029,\"x\":6,\"y\":14}],\"obstacles\":[],\"last_news_seen\":155,\"last_league_rank\":13,\"newShopBuildings\":[4,0,6,3,6,3,4,1,5,5,225,3,3,4,1,5,0,0,0,3,1,0,1,2,1,0,2,0,1,1],\"newShopDecos\":[1,4,0,1,1,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}",
  "warVillage": "{\"newShopTraps\":[6,6,3,0,0,4,2,0,2],\"cooldowns\":[],\"last_league_shuffle\":1,\"decos\":[{\"data\":18000031,\"x\":2,\"y\":36},{\"data\":18000011,\"x\":4,\"y\":36},{\"data\":18000027,\"x\":6,\"y\":38},{\"data\":18000012,\"x\":6,\"y\":40},{\"data\":18000033,\"x\":6,\"y\":36}],\"edit_mode_shown\":true,\"buildings\":[{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000001,\"x\":20,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":11,\"y\":34,\"res_timer\":0},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":10,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":8,\"y\":30},{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000014,\"x\":25,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":24,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":37,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":34,\"y\":13,\"res_timer\":120625},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000003,\"x\":12,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000005,\"x\":16,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":11,\"y\":5},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":18,\"y\":33},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":20,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":30,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":31,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":30},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":31},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":33},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":34},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":35},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":35},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":35},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":35},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":34},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":33},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":31},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":30},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":30},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":31},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":31},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":30},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":11,\"y\":10},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000013,\"x\":20,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000007,\"x\":7,\"y\":6},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000005,\"x\":17,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000003,\"x\":27,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":16,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":8,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":8,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":29,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":30,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":31,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":34,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":10,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":12,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":5,\"y\":27,\"res_timer\":120624},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":5,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":4,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":23,\"y\":37,\"res_timer\":120160},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":35,\"y\":29,\"res_timer\":120716},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":18,\"y\":37,\"res_timer\":0},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":28,\"y\":36,\"res_timer\":0},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":24,\"y\":32,\"res_timer\":120216},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":29,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":35,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":35,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":35,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":34,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":30,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":31,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":29,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":22,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":10,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000012,\"x\":24,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":21,\"y\":33,\"res_timer\":120218},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":8,\"y\":22,\"res_timer\":120687},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000011,\"x\":16,\"y\":30},{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000020,\"x\":37,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":32,\"y\":25,\"res_timer\":120626},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":10},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":31,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":30,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":29,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":9},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000013,\"x\":29,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000011,\"x\":17,\"y\":9},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":8,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":33,\"y\":20,\"res_timer\":120217},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":28,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":4,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":9},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":10},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":33,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":8,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":21,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000013,\"x\":12,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000023,\"x\":37,\"y\":24,\"res_timer\":40689},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000012,\"x\":16,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000024,\"x\":25,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000026,\"x\":20,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000022,\"x\":25,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000028,\"x\":16,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":16,\"y\":37},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000005,\"x\":25,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000003,\"x\":13,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":12,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":10,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":8,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":8,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":29,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":12,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":12,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":29,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000013,\"x\":21,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000012,\"x\":18,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000011,\"x\":25,\"y\":9},{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000023,\"x\":29,\"y\":7,\"res_timer\":40691},{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000026,\"x\":15,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":1,\"data\":1000029,\"x\":25,\"y\":4}],\"obstacles\":[],\"last_news_seen\":155,\"last_league_rank\":13,\"newShopBuildings\":[4,0,6,3,6,3,4,1,5,5,225,3,3,4,1,5,0,0,0,3,1,0,1,2,1,0,2,0,1,1],\"newShopDecos\":[1,4,0,1,1,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}"
}
```

That's the JSON file and whenever I try to retrieve the data by doing the following:

$randomVar = $data['villageJson']['buildings'];

It returns an error saying 'buildings' is ... offset.

---

So what I did is what you guys probably know is I googled why it was doing that by doing a JSON Beautifier search and what showed was an error message saying that it was not a json. Which made me scratch my head for a bit and when I remove the double quotes encapsulating the entire 'villageJson' content it now said "Strings should be wrapped in double quotes". So I came into a conclusion that this is a json string and I have to turn it into a JSON before I could call any array.

So now for the question. How do I turn this JSON String to a JSON? I had an alternative in mind by just using a search function in php and I would get my value that way but that's only if I can't get any answers here.

THanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '{"villageJson": "{\"newShopTraps\":[6,6,3,0,0,4,2,0,2],\"cooldowns\":[],\"last_league_shuffle\":1,\"decos\":[{\"data\":18000031,\"x\":2,\"y\":36},{\"data\":18000011,\"x\":4,\"y\":36},{\"data\":18000027,\"x\":6,\"y\":38},{\"data\":18000012,\"x\":6,\"y\":40},{\"data\":18000033,\"x\":6,\"y\":36}],\"edit_mode_shown\":true,\"buildings\":[{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000001,\"x\":20,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":22,\"y\":33,\"res_timer\":0},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":9,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":28,\"y\":5},{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000014,\"x\":20,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":10,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":34,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":16,\"y\":33,\"res_timer\":120625},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000003,\"x\":21,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000005,\"x\":13,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":34,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":10,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":15,\"y\":9},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":6,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":8,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":10,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":12,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":29,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000013,\"x\":13,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000007,\"x\":29,\"y\":33},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000005,\"x\":27,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000003,\"x\":27,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":27,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":30,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":30},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":31},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":31,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":34,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":35,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":33},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":34},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":19,\"y\":33,\"res_timer\":120624},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":34,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":34,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":11,\"y\":5,\"res_timer\":120160},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":25,\"y\":33,\"res_timer\":120716},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":21,\"y\":5,\"res_timer\":0},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":15,\"y\":5,\"res_timer\":0},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":10,\"y\":17,\"res_timer\":120216},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":8,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":35},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":37,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":35,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":34,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":31,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":30,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":29,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":10},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":9},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":24,\"y\":9},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":14,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000012,\"x\":13,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":24,\"y\":5,\"res_timer\":120218},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":30,\"y\":13,\"res_timer\":120687},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000011,\"x\":16,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000020,\"x\":6,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":14,\"y\":29,\"res_timer\":120626},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":6},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":5},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000013,\"x\":24,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000011,\"x\":27,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":11,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":18,\"y\":5,\"res_timer\":120217},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":28,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":34,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":35},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":34},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":33},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":31},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":30},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":5},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":6},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":9},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":10},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":12,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":29,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":10,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":30,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":25,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":17,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000013,\"x\":30,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000023,\"x\":10,\"y\":20,\"res_timer\":40689},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000012,\"x\":30,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000024,\"x\":17,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000026,\"x\":6,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000022,\"x\":17,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000028,\"x\":24,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":7,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000005,\"x\":23,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000003,\"x\":17,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":5,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":6,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":8,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":23,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000013,\"x\":18,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000012,\"x\":21,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000011,\"x\":20,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000023,\"x\":20,\"y\":9,\"res_timer\":40691},{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000026,\"x\":6,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":1,\"data\":1000029,\"x\":6,\"y\":14}],\"obstacles\":[],\"last_news_seen\":155,\"last_league_rank\":13,\"newShopBuildings\":[4,0,6,3,6,3,4,1,5,5,225,3,3,4,1,5,0,0,0,3,1,0,1,2,1,0,2,0,1,1],\"newShopDecos\":[1,4,0,1,1,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}","warVillage": "{\"newShopTraps\":[6,6,3,0,0,4,2,0,2],\"cooldowns\":[],\"last_league_shuffle\":1,\"decos\":[{\"data\":18000031,\"x\":2,\"y\":36},{\"data\":18000011,\"x\":4,\"y\":36},{\"data\":18000027,\"x\":6,\"y\":38},{\"data\":18000012,\"x\":6,\"y\":40},{\"data\":18000033,\"x\":6,\"y\":36}],\"edit_mode_shown\":true,\"buildings\":[{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000001,\"x\":20,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":11,\"y\":34,\"res_timer\":0},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":10,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":8,\"y\":30},{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000014,\"x\":25,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":24,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":37,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":34,\"y\":13,\"res_timer\":120625},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000003,\"x\":12,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000005,\"x\":16,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":11,\"y\":5},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":18,\"y\":33},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":20,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":30,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":31,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":30},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":31},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":33},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":34},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":35},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":35},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":36},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":35},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":35},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":34},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":33},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":31},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":30},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":30},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":31},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":32},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":31},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":30},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":11,\"y\":10},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000013,\"x\":20,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000007,\"x\":7,\"y\":6},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000005,\"x\":17,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000003,\"x\":27,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":16,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":8,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":8,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":29,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":30,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":31,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":34,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":10,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":12,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":5,\"y\":27,\"res_timer\":120624},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":5,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":4,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":23,\"y\":37,\"res_timer\":120160},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":35,\"y\":29,\"res_timer\":120716},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":18,\"y\":37,\"res_timer\":0},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":28,\"y\":36,\"res_timer\":0},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":24,\"y\":32,\"res_timer\":120216},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":29,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":35,\"y\":28},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":35,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":36,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":35,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":34,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":30,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":31,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":29,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":22,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":10,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000012,\"x\":24,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":21,\"y\":33,\"res_timer\":120218},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":8,\"y\":22,\"res_timer\":120687},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000011,\"x\":16,\"y\":30},{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000020,\"x\":37,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":32,\"y\":25,\"res_timer\":120626},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":33,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":10},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":32,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":31,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":30,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":29,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":9},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000013,\"x\":29,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000011,\"x\":17,\"y\":9},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":8,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":8,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":33,\"y\":20,\"res_timer\":120217},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":28,\"y\":29},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":4,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":7},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":8},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":9},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":18,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":10},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":11},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":13},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":14},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":28,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":27,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":26,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":25,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":33,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":8,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":21,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000013,\"x\":12,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000023,\"x\":37,\"y\":24,\"res_timer\":40689},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000012,\"x\":16,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000024,\"x\":25,\"y\":18},{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000026,\"x\":20,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000022,\"x\":25,\"y\":15},{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000028,\"x\":16,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":16,\"y\":37},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000005,\"x\":25,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":10,\"data\":1000003,\"x\":13,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":12,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":10,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":9,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":8,\"y\":27},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":8,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":26},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":29,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":12,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":16,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":15,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":23,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":22,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":21,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":13,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":12,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":11,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":7,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":25},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":24},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":23},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":22},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":21},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":20},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":19,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":7,\"data\":1000010,\"x\":20,\"y\":19},{\"lvl\":9,\"data\":1000009,\"x\":29,\"y\":17},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000013,\"x\":21,\"y\":12},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000012,\"x\":18,\"y\":16},{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000011,\"x\":25,\"y\":9},{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000023,\"x\":29,\"y\":7,\"res_timer\":40691},{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000026,\"x\":15,\"y\":4},{\"lvl\":1,\"data\":1000029,\"x\":25,\"y\":4}],\"obstacles\":[],\"last_news_seen\":155,\"last_league_rank\":13,\"newShopBuildings\":[4,0,6,3,6,3,4,1,5,5,225,3,3,4,1,5,0,0,0,3,1,0,1,2,1,0,2,0,1,1],\"newShopDecos\":[1,4,0,1,1,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}"}';

$data = json_decode($str,1);

$village = json_decode($data['villageJson'],1);

$randomVar = $village['buildings'];

print_r($randomVar);
```

Comment: Yeah thanks for the informative answer! I got it to work now.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `json_decode()` to turn the string into an object.

[PHP: json_decode - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Huh no wonder it wasn't working earlier. I was not using print_r(). But thanks anyways! That just confirmed what I thought should have worked.